# MainPage.xaml from Windows phone 8.0 app

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I can't find MainPage.xaml from Windows phone 8.0 app. 
I have only App.xaml. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. 
Is it code generated from Visual Studio?

Comment: Not sure if this fits here. Is this a programming question ? Could you give some context ? You probably use some assistant in VS, could you edit question with some details.

Comment: Did you  create a Windows Phone blank app ? MainPage.xaml must get generated with it..

Comment: I have a windows phone 8 app created few times ago but i don't have MainPage.xaml. Is it possible?

Comment: What is the template you have chosen while creating the project ?

Comment: MVVM (unfortunately is not a project of mine)

Comment: @AlessandroMorsiani are you sure the project owner didn't set the startup page as another .xaml page in the app manifest?

Comment: @Chubosaurus Software, you right! I have a "HomePage.xaml" exactly the same. Thank you!!

Comment: @AlessandroMorsiani np, I will put it as an answer (please mark it).  So it will help out the next person that might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since this project wasn't original yours.   I will assume that the owner set the default page to another .XAML file.  Check the app manifest setting to make sure.  See screenshot.

> WMAppManifest.xml

[image: WMAppManifest.xml]

As you can see my default page is set to a PanormaPage1.xaml